# Function parameters structure based on STDIN - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, stdout, stdin

The challenge description:

In a garden, there are shelters that are randomly distributed, and children who play freely. Suddenly the first drops of rain begin to fall one after the other. To hide the children, everyone will move towards the shelter closest to him. Your mission then is to help each child to locate the corresponding shelter.

To simplify the problem, we equate shelters and children with points, and we also assume that the capacity of shelters is infinite. Each child and each shelter is characterized by three parameters:

unique identifiers
X
Y
Input specification:
The code will be executed against several test cases.

Each test is described as follows:

First row contains an integer B between 1 and 100 which indicates the number of shelters.
B lines follow each one contains 3 pieces of information:
The unique identifier of the Bname shelter in the form of a character string less than or equal to 20 characters long, and which does not contain spaces.
The abscissa X of the center of the shelter, as an integer between -1000 and 1000 .
The ordinate Y of the center of the shelter, as an integer between -1000 and 1000 .
After another line which contains an integer K between 1 and 1000 which indicates the number of children.
K lines follow, each one contains 3 pieces of information:
The unique identifier of the child Kname in the form of a character string less than or equal to 20 characters long, and which does not contain spaces.
The abscissa X of the center of the child, as an integer between -1000 and 1000 .
The ordinate Y of the center of the child, as an integer between -1000 and 1000 .
Output specifications:
For each child display a single line containing the correspondence between him and the nearest shelter like: Kname Bname

NB: If there are several optimal shelters, please display the first one found in the list.

Scoring
B and K ≤10 (10 Points)
3 other test cases, each 30 Points

Please I have this STDIN input.

```
3
Box1 8 -6
Box2 6 10
Box3 4 5
4
pA 8 8
pB 2 7
pC -2 1
pD -5 -7
```

and this STDOUT output

```
pA Box2
pB Box3
pC Box3
pD Box1
```

I have a function but the question is how the structure of the parameters should be, something like that maybe saveChildsToShelter(3, ['box1', 8, -6], 4, ['pA', 8, 8]), or another structure?

Because the coding challenging platform I'm practicing in, doesn't offer the type of input data structure (*array, object...*)?

Thanks.

Comment: How would we know wihout seeing the challenge?

Comment: Yes, you're right but the challenge is in written French? I will post a translation of it, it's ready to check it now? @Teemu

Comment: You have to produce a complete program, not just a function. There isn't any restriction about the structure of your program. It has to be able to read the provided input (from `stdin`) and to produce the output in the described format (on `stdout`). Everything else is up to you.

Comment: Aaah okay, maybe you mean I'm required to write the full program that can read from STDIN, and he is requiring the *required('readline')*, like on hackerrank platform?@axiac